# Adding a new object to List then the already stored objects will be overwritten by the new one

Tags: c#

I would like to ask some help! I write automation test using WebDriver and I have the code below. The purpose of this static method is to collect objects from a a certian part of the page.

As you can see I use for loop to modify the locator value and I test the locator whether it is displayed. If it is displayed then I initiate the MenuGroupObject object and I put it into a List object which is the return value at the end.

Please, take a look at the output result below the code snippet.

```c#
public static List<MenuGroupPageObject> GetListOfMenuGroups(IWebDriver webDriver)
    {
        var listOfMenuGroupPageObjects = new List<MenuGroupPageObject>();

        var menuGroupLocatorPattern = MenuBarLocatorHelper.GetMenuBarRootLocator() +
                                      MenuBarLocatorHelper.GetLocatorPatternForMenuGroups();

        for (var i = 1; i < 20; i++)
        {
            var realMenuGroupNameLocator = menuGroupLocatorPattern.Replace(
                MenuBarLocatorHelper.GetThePureMenuGroupLocatorPatternForMenuGroups(), i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

            if(SafeElementHandler.IsElementPresent(webDriver,By.XPath(realMenuGroupNameLocator)))
            {
                var menuGroupObject = new MenuGroupPageObject(webDriver, realMenuGroupNameLocator);
                listOfMenuGroupPageObjects.Add(menuGroupObject);

                foreach (MenuGroupPageObject listOfMenuGroupPageObject in listOfMenuGroupPageObjects)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("mainlocators in the bag round: " + i + "... " + listOfMenuGroupPageObject.GetMainLocator());
                }
            }
        }

        return listOfMenuGroupPageObjects;
    }
```

So, the the result is this:

```
    mainlocators in the bag round: 1... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[1]

mainlocators in the bag round: 2... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[2]
mainlocators in the bag round: 2... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[2]

mainlocators in the bag round: 3... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[3]
mainlocators in the bag round: 3... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[3]
mainlocators in the bag round: 3... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[3]

mainlocators in the bag round: 4... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[4]
mainlocators in the bag round: 4... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[4]
mainlocators in the bag round: 4... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[4]
mainlocators in the bag round: 4... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[4]

mainlocators in the bag round: 5... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[5]
mainlocators in the bag round: 5... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[5]
mainlocators in the bag round: 5... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[5]
mainlocators in the bag round: 5... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[5]
mainlocators in the bag round: 5... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[5]
```

What you should notice is that, in every round the already stored object(s) will be overwritten by the newest.
But, it should be something like this:

```
    mainlocators in the bag round: 1... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[1]

mainlocators in the bag round: 2... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[1]
mainlocators in the bag round: 2... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[2]

mainlocators in the bag round: 3... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[1]
mainlocators in the bag round: 3... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[2]
mainlocators in the bag round: 3... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[3]

mainlocators in the bag round: 4... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[1]
mainlocators in the bag round: 4... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[2]
mainlocators in the bag round: 4... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[3]
mainlocators in the bag round: 4... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[4]

mainlocators in the bag round: 5... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[1]
mainlocators in the bag round: 5... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[2]
mainlocators in the bag round: 5... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[3]
mainlocators in the bag round: 5... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[4]
mainlocators in the bag round: 5... //div[@id='contentContainer']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='leftHandMenubar']/ul[5]
```

My question is that, what is wrong? I checked the List<> in c# and I haven't found anything which if it is lacking (missing constructor parameter, or like) can cause something like this.

Comment: I read the post three times and have no idea what is your actual problem.

Comment: Use a debugger to solve this.

Comment: The problem is on the `MenuGroupPageObject` object. Check your constructor and check the `GetMainLocator` method.

Comment: Yosi, if you take a look the result then you can see that in every round when a MenuGroupPageObject is added into the list and the objects in the List is listed the amount of the objects in the List is increased by 1 but the List contains always the same object. I want store the objects which are not the same. The expected result contains what I want.

Comment: mcabral, thanks for the hint! In the MenuGroupPageObject the locator was a static field. This was the problem! I changed it to not static and it is working fine! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment the MenuPageObject object had a static field.